# BIRT 2.3.2 to 2.6.0 upgrade error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, upgrade, birt

I am getting the following error when I try to upgrade the BIRT version that is embedded in my custom web application

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EmitterInfo.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/lang/Boolean;Lorg/eclipse/birt/core/framework/IConfigurationElement;)V
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.extension.internal.ExtensionManager.loadEmitterExtensionDefns(ExtensionManager.java:593)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.extension.internal.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:142)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.extension.internal.ExtensionManager.createInstance(ExtensionManager.java:155)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.extension.internal.ExtensionManager.getInstance(ExtensionManager.java:164)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineHelper.<init>(ReportEngineHelper.java:79)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine.<init>(ReportEngine.java:127)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:18)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory$1.run(ReportEngineFactory.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory.createReportEngine(ReportEngineFactory.java:14)
```

The error occurs in the following line in the code

```
birtEngine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
```

I have checked the Web App Libraries and I have the 2.6.0 runtime lib jars in it.

Please help

Comment: Have you replaced the lib and plugins jars with 2.6 versions?
 It looks like some old jars are still being referenced in the app

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yes, I had placed the lib/jars but not the plugins. Once I did that everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to JoseK, issue has been resolved. You need the jars and the plugins.